# Is this a real grammar structure のほうがverb-ていい

Tags: grammar

> 同じ怒られるタイプなら、はまじやブー太郎**のほうがスッキリしていていい**じゃない
>   If you're the same "getting told off" type (as Nagasawa), Hamaji and Buu Tarou's side feels refreshing and is good, isn't it?

Is the grammar as straight forward as my translation or does のほうが link up with いい to mean "better" in some sense? I also wasn't sure if -ていい was doing something like -てもいい suggesting that she is **allowed** to feel refreshed.

Context: The speaker believes that there are two types of people who always get told off. Nagasawa belongs to one type and both Hamaji and Buu Taro belong to the other type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sentence can be technically parsed in more than one way. But in the last half of this sentence, I feel there are one verbal phrase (スッキリしている) and one adjective (いい) combined with て, *sharing the same subject* (はまじやブー太郎のほう).

In other words, the sentence is saying "はまじやブー太郎のほうがスッキリしている" **and thus** "はまじやブー太郎のほうがいい". And yes, the latter part means Hamaji and Buu Taro are *better* (than Nagasawa, who is not スッキリしている).

By the way, this スッキリしている refers to their characters (ie, スッキリした性格をしている). スッキリした性格 is a synonym of [さばさばした性格／さっぱりした性格](http://thesaurus.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%95%E3%81%B0%E3%81%95%E3%81%B0%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E6%80%A7%E6%A0%BC), and roughly means "not to be mentally affected easily" or "to be quick to recover from gloomy moods" in this situation. I said this because I don't know if *refreshing* has such a connotation.

Answer (score 1):

No, のほうが does not link up with いい.

I would translate this as

> As long as you're the type to get yelled at, isn't it better to be nice and crisp like Hamaji and Buu Tarou?

Comment: I am afraid that 「のほうが」 does link up with 「いい」 (and does so rather strongly and directly if I may add).